# rails while adding second nested form new fields, first nested form fields disappers in edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables

1) client
2) family
3) emplyoee

While adding new fields in new form everthing works perfect

But in edit form if i add nested attributes for family first 
and then i add nested attributes for employee then the fields added for family are gone and fields are added for employee

```
        class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
         self.primary_key = "id"
         has_many :familys , dependent: :destroy, :foreign_key => 'client_id'
         accepts_nested_attributes_for :familys , allow_destroy: true
         has_many :employees , dependent: :destroy, :foreign_key => 'client_id'
         accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees , allow_destroy: true
        end


        class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :client              
        end


        class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :client              
        end


       #-------_form.html.erb-----------------------------#

        <%= nested_form_for(@client) do |f| %>

        <div><%= f.submit 'addfamily',:name => "add_n_tenpo" %></div>

        <%= f.fields_for :familys  do |w| %>
         <tr>
            <td class="label_width">巡店店舗</td>
            <td><%= w.text_field :tenpo_code_1, class: 'form-control tenpoautofill' %></td>
            <td><%= w.text_field :tenpo_code_2, class: 'form-control tenpoautofill' %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>

        <div><%= f.submit 'addemployee',:name => "add_nw_tenpo" %></div>

        <%= f.fields_for :employees  do |nw| %>
        <tr>
              <td class="label_width">巡店店舗</td>
              <td><%= nw.text_field :nw_tenpo_code_1, class: 'form-control' %></td>
              <td><%= nw.text_field :nw_tenpo_code_2, class: 'form-control' %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>

        <% end %>
```

Comment: can you post the code for form?

Comment: I have edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Because You need to explicitly pass values for `familys` and `employees` in nested form for edit action, this doesn't effect your new action's form because in new action `@client` is nil so it need to pass value for edit action.

Try this

```
<%= nested_form_for(@client) do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :familys_attributes, @client.familys  do |w| %>
     <tr>
        <td class="label_width">巡店店舗</td>
        <td><%= w.text_field :tenpo_code_1, class: 'form-control tenpoautofill' %></td>
        <td><%= w.text_field :tenpo_code_2, class: 'form-control tenpoautofill' %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :employees_attributes, @client.employees  do |nw| %>
    <tr>
          <td class="label_width">巡店店舗</td>
          <td><%= nw.text_field :nw_tenpo_code_1, class: 'form-control' %></td>
          <td><%= nw.text_field :nw_tenpo_code_2, class: 'form-control' %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: I got this error

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `tenpo_code_1' for #<Family::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f6920a1ab68>):

Comment: @anjali do you have field `tenpo_code_1` in `Family` model?

Comment: could you tell what fields are in family and employee model?

Comment: Yes i have tenpo_code_1  field in family model 
and nw_tenpo_code_1 in employee model

Comment: then please try this

`<%= w.text_field :tenpo_code_1, value: w.tenpo_code_1, class: 'form-control tenpoautofill' %>`

and so on for employee nested form